# Java POI, Does palettes work with SS model?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Im doing a conversion to the ss model.

Before I was doing something like this:

```
HSSFPalette palette = wb.getCustomPalette();
            //replacing the standard red with freebsd.org red
    palette.setColorAtIndex(HSSFColor.RED.index,
            (byte) 255,  //RGB red (0-255)
            (byte) 160,    //RGB green
            (byte) 160     //RGB blue
    );
```

I dont see any references to Palette in the SS model.......any suggestions?

Comment: I've got a feeling that it might be .xls only, and .xlsx does it differently...

Comment: so should I remove this code all together?  All my other code I was able to convert

Comment: I have a feeling that the XLSX format stores colours differently, so you'd need to have XLS vs XLSX specific code, BICBW